# MERN stack : Adding delete button in React with table. Got my backend setup with delete, but don't know how to put in up in my Frontend(React)

Tags: reactjs, axios, backend

Backend : Delete route (Working with postman, so don't think need to change that)

```
const Student = require("../models/student_model");

const deleteStudent=(req,resp)=>{
   Student.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(
       ()=>{
           resp.status(200).json({
               message: "Deleted"
           })
       }
   )
   .catch(
       (error)=>{
            resp.status(400).json({
                error : error
            })
       }
   )

}
module.exports= deleteStudent
```

Frontend: (Need help with how to setup my onClick ={deleteStudent} function. I am using axios.delete)

```
<div className='table_content'>
       <input type='text' value={search} onChange={changeHandler} placeholder='Search'/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <th>Registration Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Subjects</th>
            </tr>
            {searchOp.map(data=>
                <tr key={data._id}>
                    <td><button>Edit</button> <button onClick={deleteStudent}>Delete</button></td>
                    <td>{data.registrationNumber}</td>
                    <td>{data.name}</td>
                    <td>{data.grade}</td>
                    <td>{data.subjects}</td>
                </tr>
                )}
        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So let me help you with the `deleteStudent` function. This would be the code:

```
const component = () => {

    const deleteStudent = (_id) => {

        axios.delete('YOUR ENDPOINT URL', {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params : {
                id: _id
            }
        })
            .then( resp => {
                console.log(resp.message);
            })
            .catch( err => console.error );
    }


    return <div className='table_content'>
        <input type='text' value={search} onChange={changeHandler} placeholder='Search' />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <th>Registration Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Subjects</th>
            </tr>
            {searchOp.map(data =>
                <tr key={data._id}>
                    <td><button>Edit</button> <button onClick={() => deleteStudent(data._id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    <td>{data.registrationNumber}</td>
                    <td>{data.name}</td>
                    <td>{data.grade}</td>
                    <td>{data.subjects}</td>
                </tr>
            )}
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

There you can see that I am using `axios.delete` function. You have to use the url of your endpoint, for example, http://localhost:5000/deleteItem

You may also need to enable CORS in your backend. You can find more information [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

If you want the items searchOp to automatically re-render in your web page you may need to use `useState` hook, you can find more information about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: Thanks Erick. Working perfectly. Now just working on how to rerender table after I pressed delete.